# ion-spinner while waiting for music to load (ionic 2/angular 2)

Tags: javascript, android, angular, typescript, ionic2

In my music app, I have a "click" function that makes an http request and plays the .mp3 file from the server. My problem is that sometimes it takes a while for the app to load the audio from the server that is why I added an ion-spinner. I am trying to make it so when the music is loading in the  `this.media.load();` the ion-spinner is shown and when it is done loading the spinner is hidden.

I don't know if ill have to implement a listener or not

**Home.html**

```
<ion-card-content (click)="play(sound)">
      <div class="wrapper">
      <ion-spinner class="color-green" name="bubble"></ion-spinner>
      <img src="{{ sound.imageUrl }}" />       
      </div>     
</ion-card-content>
```

**Home.ts**

```
/* Plays a sound, pausing other playing sounds if necessary */
  play(sound) {
    console.log(sound)
    if(this.media) {      
    this.media.pause();      
    }
   this.media = new Audio(sound.file);    
   this.media.load();
   this.media.play();
 }
```

Comment: why not use `*ngIf` to toggle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `*ngIf` to your spinner

```
<ion-spinner class="color-green" name="bubble" *ngIf="showSpinner"></ion-spinner>
```

then is the `.ts` file

```
showSpinner:boolean;
...
// On the click action set to true
this.showSpinner = true;
// When the http returns with the audio file set to false
this.showSpinner = false;
```